# Using ArcPy replaceDataSource into Feature Dataset

Tags: arcpy, feature-dataset, data-source

I have Python script replacing data from library with individual project-related data (using `lyr.replaceDataSource()`).  Sometimes the data is directed to a GBD and it works fine, but when the new path is a feature dataset within the GDB, it doesn't work. It runs without error (does clipping OK) but the data in the relevant MXD still points to the original source.

Updating and fixing data sources with `arcpy.mapping` says `Do not include the names of feature datasets in the workspace path`. Feature datasets are part of the workspace. If a feature class, for example, is moved from being a stand-alone feature class into a feature dataset, a map document will still open without the layer being broken", and "If a layer or table within a map document or layer file is moved into or out of a feature dataset, their links should not be broken."

See end of my script:

```
def list_files(dir):
    r = []
    ldir = os.listdir(dir)
    for i in ldir:
        if i [-4:] == '.shp':
            r.append(i)
    return r

def get_date(now):
    year = now.year
    year = str(year)
    year = year.lstrip("20")

    month = now.month
    if month < 10:
        month = "0" + str(month)
    else: 
        month = str(month)

    day = now.day
    if day < 10:
        day = "0" + str(day)
    else:
        day = str(day)

    date = year + month + day
    return date

def path_file(path):
    path_split = path.split(os.sep)

    path_len = len(path_split)
    fname = path_split[path_len-1]
    pname = path.rstrip(fname)

    #fname_len = len(fname)
    #fname = fname [:fname_len-4]
    pname = pname.rstrip(os.sep)

    return fname, pname   

def list_lyrs (txt_lst):
    txt_lst += ';'
    #arcpy.AddMessage(txt_lst)
    lyr_list = list()

    txtChar = ''
    txtItem = ''

    for i in txt_lst:
        #arcpy.AddMessage(i)
        if i !=';' and i != r"'":
            txtChar = txtChar + i
        if i ==';':
            txtItem = ''
            for i_txt in txtChar:
                if i_txt == os.sep:
                    txtItem = ''
                if i_txt != os.sep:
                    txtItem += i_txt 

            lyr_list.append(txtItem)
            txtItem = ''
            txtChar = ''
    return lyr_list




import arcpy   
from arcpy import env 
import os, string
import csv
import re
import datetime
import sys
import copy




#Get parameters
flayers = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
flist = list_lyrs(flayers)
out_lst = copy.copy(flist)     #copy list without inheritance
#arcpy.AddMessage(out_lst)

#arcpy.AddMessage(flist)

project_n = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
#project_n = '99999_99999'

out_path = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2)
#out_path = r'C:\Users\xxxx\xxxxx\Python_scripts\Batch_Clip\Test_Results'

clip_fshape = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(3)
#clip_fshape = r'C:\Users\xxxx\xxxxx\Python_scripts\Batch_Clip\Test_Results\Clip_Area.shp'


env.workspace = out_path
env.overwriteOutput = True


now = datetime.datetime.now()
date = get_date(now)   

#Special Cahacters
special_char = ' -"!£$%^&*()[]{};#:@~,./<>?\|*.'
trans = string.maketrans(special_char, '_'*len(special_char)) 

#This creates a list of the output files with folder path

for n, i in enumerate(out_lst):
    #clean_i = str(i)
    #clean_i = i.translate(trans)
    out_file = out_path + os.sep  + date + '_' + project_n + '_' + i
    out_lst [n] = out_file

#arcpy.AddMessage(out_lst)

#sys.exit()

try: 
    #clip the data
    lyrs = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd)

    for lyr in lyrs:
        #arcpy.AddMessage (lyr.name)
        for n, i in enumerate (flist):
            #arcpy.AddMessage(i)
            if lyr.name == i:

                #arcpy.AddMessage(lyr)
                #arcpy.AddMessage(out_path)
                nme = lyr.name
                nme = str(nme)
                nme = nme.translate(trans)
                nme = project_n + '_' + nme
                output_to = out_path + os.sep + nme
                gb_source = lyr.dataSource
                #arcpy.AddMessage(gb_source) 
                arcpy.AddMessage(out_path)
                arcpy.AddMessage(output_to)
                arcpy.AddMessage(nme)
                #sys.exit()



                fname, pname = path_file(out_lst[n])
                arcpy.Clip_analysis(lyr, clip_fshape, output_to)
                #arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management(lyr, "INTERSECT", clip_fshape)
                #arcpy.CopyFeatures_management (lyr, output_to)
                try:
                    lyr.replaceDataSource(out_path, "FILEGDB_WORKSPACE", nme)
                except:
                    mess = "Failed to replace source if " + fname
                    arcpy.AddMessage(mess)
except:
    arcpy.AddMessage("Batch clip failed.")
    arcpy.AddMessage("If output feature class already exists, try deleting them.")

arcpy.RefreshActiveView()
```

Comment: Could you add some other parts of your code to give information about `nme`, `name`, `pname`, `output_to`, `out_path`? What are their values?

Comment: see the whole below

Comment: Get parameters
flayers = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
flist = list_lyrs(flayers)
out_lst = copy.copy(flist)     #copy list without inheritance
#arcpy.AddMessage(out_lst)

#arcpy.AddMessage(flist)

project_n = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
#project_n = '99999_99999'

out_path = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2)
#out_path = r'C:\Users\xxx\xxx\Python_scripts\Batch_Clip\Test_Results'

clip_fshape = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(3)
#clip_fshape = r'C:\Users\xxx\xxx\Python_scripts\Batch_Clip\Test_Results\Clip_Area.shp'

Comment: for n, i in enumerate(out_lst):
    #clean_i = str(i)
    #clean_i = i.translate(trans)
    out_file = out_path + os.sep  + date + '_' + project_n + '_' + i
    out_lst [n] = out_file

Comment: I posted the whole script,

Comment: I have run into the same issue. I have replaced my datasource without referencing the feature dataset name as described here but the link comes back broken and if I manually update a single link, the rest of the layers in that feature dataset do not restore their links (using 10.6.1). Also I have checked and the datasource is definitely pointing to the gdb.